# What’s the Chabad psak on Beit Yosef and sinta (sirloin steak) in Israel?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, eretz-yisrael, chabad

I’m in Israel and most Ashkenazim don’t eat sinta (sirloin steak) but I was wondering if Chabad does.

Comment: What is "sinta"?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Dov and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Bear in mind the audience has a lot of non-Israelis - you will need to better explain your question for them to understand it - please do so by [edit]ing your question directly. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Sinta is the Hebrew for what Americans call sirloin

Comment: Can your explain why people in Israel don't eat sirloin steak?

Comment: @GershonGold could be the op is referring to the widely circulated misunderstanding and assumption that Ashkenazim are not allowed to eat from the back of the cow no matter what